# Failed to access the WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl

Hello I am trying setting up a simple WSDL program in Java but I get the following error, any advices? I am fairly new at this, and this program is my first one of sorts.

Thank you,

```
package de.vs.webServices.clientSide;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import de.vs.webServices.serverSide.ZeichenketteInt;

public class ZeichenketteClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/vs/Zeichenkette?wsdl");

QName qname = new       QName("http://serverSide.webServices.vs.de/","ZeichenketteImplService");

Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

ZeichenketteInt zeichenketteInt = service.getPort(ZeichenketteInt.class);

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int nr=0;
do {
    System.out.println("Waehlen Sie die Nummer eines Befehls oder 0 um das Programm zu beenden: ");
    System.out.println("1. Zeichen Doppeln");
    System.out.println("2. Zeichenkette Verdoppeln");
    System.out.println("3. ZeichenketteSpiegeln");
    System.out.println("4. ZeichenketteLange");
    nr = sc.nextInt();
    String zeichenkette = null;
    switch (nr) {
    case 1:
        System.out
                .println("Schreiben Sie die gewunschte Zeichenkette: ");
        zeichenkette = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Ergebnis: "
                + zeichenketteInt.zeichenDoppeln(zeichenkette));
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out
                .println("Schreiben Sie die gewunschte Zeichenkette: ");
        zeichenkette = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Ergebnis: "
                + zeichenketteInt.zeichenKetteVerdoppeln(zeichenkette));

        break;
    case 3:
        System.out
                .println("Schreiben Sie die gewunschte Zeichenkette: ");
        zeichenkette = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Ergebnis: "
                + zeichenketteInt.zeichenKetteSpiegeln(zeichenkette));
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out
                .println("Schreiben Sie die gewunschte Zeichenkette: ");
        zeichenkette = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Ergebnis: "
                + zeichenketteInt.zeichenKetteLange(zeichenkette));
        break;
    }
} while (nr!=0);
sc.close();
```

}}

This is the error that I get:

```
        Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://localhost:9999/vs/Zeichenkette?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Unknown Source)
    at de.vs.webServices.clientSide.ZeichenketteClient.main(ZeichenketteClient.java:19)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Please check the service, which might not be running on the given details.

Answer (score 3):

The part of the error that says: "refused: connect"
is telling you that the server (localhost in this case) rejected your connection request.

I would check that the URI: http://localhost:9999/vs/Zeichenkette?wsdl actually returns a WSDL document. Just open it in a web browser and see what you get back. If the browser can't open it, Java can't either. Once the browser will open it, Java should have no problem with it (though it occasionally happens that the browser reads it fine and permissions in Java stop you, this doesn't appear to be one of those cases).

Then I suggest looking to make certain that the server port is open (IPTables, AV, things like that can block it). Note that this is not likely your problem, since the error is reading the WSDL. I'm looking ahead to after the WSDL loads.